# In Markdown, how to format italicized text in a quotation?

Tags: markdown, italic

In Markdown, how to format italicized text in a quotation?

```
    *italicized text*
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indenting 4 spaces in Markdown indicates a [code block](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#precode): a `pre` element for displaying code or pre-formatted text. Markdown syntax is ignored inside code blocks, hence why your example doesn't work.

You need to use the [blockquote syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#blockquote):

```
> *italicized text*
```

Comment: Also: Multiple paragraphs within the blockquote need their own starting and ending asterisk. You cannot use a single pair of asterisks to italicise several paragraphs. (which, now I come to experiment, is just like asterisk behavior outside a blockquote, although this was obscured for me because Vim's Markdown syntax highlighting does allow this)

Answer (score 3):

> *Like this?*

Here's the code:

```
>*Like this?*
```

You denote block quotes with `>` characters. Indenting four spaces creates a code block, which you cannot insert italicized text into.